# FUSE ESB, hibernate, mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, cxf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm building cxf application, which will be run under FUSE ESB.

Usually i was creating application only for exchange data, but now i have to create application which will have connection to mysql.

I've started to build configuration under cxf, but i found one problem.

When i'm adding class:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0
```

to my `<Import-Package>` my application dissapear from avalible cxf application on FUSE ESB.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>
                       ......

                        com.mchange.v2.c3p0,
                      ......
                       <DynamicImport-Package>...</DynamicImport-Package>

                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When i delete `com.mchange.v2.c3p0` from pom.xml, application apprears.

What do i have to do?

Comment: You may want to read a complete tutorial on how to use hibernate with MySQL on Fuse ESB platform: http://lukaszbaran.com/blog/?p=259

Answer (score 0):

I guess your bundle is not being started because can't resolve com.mchange.v2.c3p0 dependency. By default FuseESB not contains C3P0 dependencies, so you need to include them with your project or deploy them as a separate bundle.

If you provide the dependency in your own bundle you must export the c3p0 packages or add them as a private package. Something like this

```
   ...
   <Private-Package>
      ...
      com.mchange.*
      ...
    </Private-Package>
    ...
```

Of course you need to add the maven dependency for c3p0 in your pom.

Anyway you should read Lukasz's blog entry.